# Sub optimal algorithm for linear programming

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the linear programming problem
\begin{align}
f^* = \max_{x}&~p^Tx~\\~&A^Tx\leq b~,~0\leq x_i\leq 1
\end{align}where $c$ is a $n\times 1 $ vector, $A$ is a $n\times c$ matrix and $b$ is a $c \times 1$vector. Here $x=[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is the $n \times 1$ vector to be found. Thus, in addition to the box constraint $0\leq x_i\leq 1$, we have $c$ constraints. It is also known that $p,A,b$ are all element-wise positive. Assume that this problem is feasible and let $(x^*,\lambda^*)$ be the optimal solutions for the primal and dual respectively. Note that $\lambda^*$ is a $c\times 1$ vector.

Consider the function
\begin{align}
d(\lambda)=\max_{x}(p-A\lambda)^Tx+\lambda^Tb~,~0\leq x_i \leq 1
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a $c \times 1$ vector. It is not hard to see that $d(\lambda^*)=f^*$. Define the vector $r$ such that $$r_i=[p-A\lambda^*]_i$$ where $[]_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ entry.

Thus
\begin{align}
d(\lambda^*)=\max_{x}r^Tx+\lambda^Tb~,~0\leq x_i \leq 1
\end{align}
Now, consider the following strategy constructing the $n\times 1$ vector $y$
\begin{align}
y_i = \begin{cases}1 ~,& r_i>0 \\0~,& r_i \leq 0\end{cases} 
\end{align}
You can see the motivation of defining $y$ from $d(\lambda^*)$. Given this,

- Can $y$ violate the constraints?
- Can we comment on the gap $$f^*-p^Ty$$ in terms of $p,A,b,n,c$?

if anyone is interested, background:
This is from an engineering problem. Typically $c$ won't be more than 2, thus that many constraints. $n$ will run into millions of variables. $p,A,b,n,c$ comes from our data. In some sense, finding $\lambda^*$ is an easier problem for us. And also from an engineering perspective not related to linear programming, $y$ is much easier to implement in our system rather than solving a linear programming system. Often, empirically, for our data (for smaller sampled sets), we have seen that it does well also. Is there any justification?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $y$ can violate the constraints. The one about box constraints ($0 \leq y \leq 1$) is OK by how $y$ is defined, the problem is the other one ($A^T y \leq b$). First I tried getting a feasibility proof unsuccessfully, then I decided to build a reproducible counterexample using Python:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate a random instance according to the conditions stated by OP (small c, larger n).
n = 150
c = 2

# Build p, A and b, which are elementwise positive.
np.random.seed(1)
p = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
A = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n,c))
b = np.random.uniform(0,1, c)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem. 
# Note that we'll solve the primal problem only to get the dual variable lambda^*
x = cp.Variable(n)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(p.T@x),
                 [A.T @ x <= b, 
                  x <= 1,
                  x >= 0 ])
prob.solve()

print("A dual solution is")
print(prob.constraints[0].dual_value)

# Construct the suggested heuristic solution, starting from the dual solution:
lambda_opt = prob.constraints[0].dual_value
r = p - np.matmul(A, lambda_opt)
y = (r > 0).astype(int)

# Verify feasibility for y:
print("Check nonpositive:", (A.T @ y) -b )
```

This piece of code outputs the array [0.138349, 0.11109537] at the last line, therefore, $A^T y - b \leq 0$ doesn't hold and $y$ is unfeasible. As a conclusion, without further information or hypotheses about $A, b$ and $p$, the proposed approach won't work in general.

Regarding the second part of your question, it reminds me about Approximation Algorithms. I cite from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm):

> In computer science and operations research, approximation algorithms are efficient algorithms that find approximate solutions to optimization problems (in particular NP-hard problems) with provable guarantees on the distance of the returned solution to the optimal one.

Assuming the problem of finding $\lambda^*$ easier as you mention, there are two scenarios:

1) If you can find $\lambda^*$ by other means and not solving the linear problem nor its dual, then you could use complementary slackness conditions to try find $x^*$. This somewhat relates to what you are building with the binding/nonbinding dual constraints (i.e. $r_i$ values). There are several examples available on how to procede, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1781926/203744), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2711824/203744) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2005638/203744).

2) If the dual problem is "easier" to solve, your approach sounds similar to using a primal-dual method. You can read an explanation on how it works at Section 5.1 of [this document](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2017/course/TDA206/lecture-notes-week-04.pdf), while [the original source where it was proposed for solving linear programs](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2008/RM1709.pdf) is several decades old.<sup>1</sup>

The general idea will be as follows:

1. Find a feasible dual solution $\lambda$.
2. Given $\lambda$, find some $x$ that minimizes the violation of complementary slackness in the primal problem. (This is the step that reminds me of what you are trying to approach when constructing $y$).
3. If complementary slackness holds, $y$ is optimal, and the algorithm terminates.
4. Otherwise, change $\lambda$ so as to improve the dual objective, and go to 2.

---

<sup>1</sup> Dantzig, George Bernard, Lester Randolph Ford Jr, and Delbert Ray Fulkerson. *A PRIMAL--DUAL ALGORITHM*. No. P-778. RAND CORP SANTA MONICA CA, 1956.